# How to set the gflags 'positional_parameters_enforcement' flag

Tags: python, google-drive-api, oauth2client

How are you supposed to set this programatically for the oauth2 module?  I have tried the following, but get a key error:

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials
import gflags

gflags.FLAGS['--positional_parameters_enforcement'] = 'EXCEPTION'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More reliably, this can be set in the following way:

```
import oauth2client.util
oauth2client.util.positional_parameter_enforcement = \
    oauth2client.util.POSITIONAL_IGNORE

from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

After consulting `help(glfags.Flag)` I identified that you set the `value` property like so:

```
import gflags

gflags['positional_parameters_enforcement'].value = 'EXCEPTION'
```

Excellent!  Although, now contrary to the documentation, the warnings are being suppressed and I have no exceptions.